# odata.track-changes leads to error 500 'Window end time must be greater than start time'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I would like to use the *Outlook REST API* to read calendar items from an Exchange Server 2019 CU2.

But as soon as I'm adding the
`Prefer: odata.track-changes` HTML-Header for getting a `deltaToken`, the server answers:

**Error 500**

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"Window end time must be greater than start time REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/."}}
```

I can **reproduce** the error with this code snippet **under any account** on this exchange server instance.

```
$url = "https://myexchangeserver/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2004-08-21T22:00:00Z&endDateTime=2034-08-21T21:59:59Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3DPropertyId%20eq%20%27Binary%200x0FFF%27)"
$output = "C:\temp\1.json"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain")
$wc.Headers.Clear();
$wc.Headers.Add("Prefer: odata.track-changes")
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

I checked the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` many times, but the *start is smaller than the end*.

I have searched the **Exchange Server logs** and found this *error stack*:

```
DispatchException=System.ArgumentException: Window end time must be greater than start time
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.SyncCalendar.SyncCalendar..ctor(CalendarSyncState syncState  IStoreSession session  StoreObjectId folderId  GetPropertiesToFetchDelegate getPropertiesToFetchDelegate  ExDateTime windowStart  ExDateTime windowEnd  Boolean includeAdditionalDataInResponse  Int32 maxChangesReturned  Boolean adjustStartAndEndForAllDayEvents)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.SyncCalendar.InternalExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.ServiceCommand`1.DetectDuplicatedCallOrExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.ServiceCommand`1.Execute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.<>c__DisplayClass338_0`1.<InvokeOwsServiceCommand>b__0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.CallWithExceptionHandling(ExecutionOption executionOption  Action action)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.InvokeOwsServiceCommand[TResponse](Func`1 commandCreator  ExecutionOption executionOption  Boolean throwOnNullResponse)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.RequestDetailsLoggerBase`1.TrackLatency[TResult](Enum latencyMetadata  Func`1 method)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewSyncCommand`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<SyncCalendar>b__1()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceHelper.HandleResponseCode(ResponseCodeType responseCodeType  Action delegateAction  Action`1 handlerAction)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewSyncCommand`1.SyncCalendar(IExchangeService exchangeService  PagingTokenFlags flags  String& skipToken  String& deltaToken)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewTrackChangesCommand.InternalExecute(IExchangeService exchangeService)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ExchangeServiceCommand`2.InternalExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.<Execute>b__9_0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.RequestDetailsLoggerBase`1.TrackLatency[TResult](Enum latencyMetadata  Func`1 method)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.EntityContainersCommand`2.Execute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Diagnostics.ServicesPerformanceTracker.RunOperationWithTrackingADAndRpcPerformance(Action method  Enum adCount  Enum adLatency  Enum rpcCount  Enum rpcLatency)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.Execute(ODataRequest request)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.Dispatch(HttpContextBase httpContext  AsyncCallback asyncCallback  CheckpointTracker checkpointTracker  ServiceModel serviceModel  IComponentConfiguration`1 configuration);ServiceDiagnostics_ReportException=System.ArgumentException: Window end time must be greater than start time
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.SyncCalendar.SyncCalendar..ctor(CalendarSyncState syncState  IStoreSession session  StoreObjectId folderId  GetPropertiesToFetchDelegate getPropertiesToFetchDelegate  ExDateTime windowStart  ExDateTime windowEnd  Boolean includeAdditionalDataInResponse  Int32 maxChangesReturned  Boolean adjustStartAndEndForAllDayEvents)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.SyncCalendar.InternalExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.ServiceCommand`1.DetectDuplicatedCallOrExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.ServiceCommand`1.Execute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.<>c__DisplayClass338_0`1.<InvokeOwsServiceCommand>b__0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.CallWithExceptionHandling(ExecutionOption executionOption  Action action)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.InvokeOwsServiceCommand[TResponse](Func`1 commandCreator  ExecutionOption executionOption  Boolean throwOnNullResponse)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.RequestDetailsLoggerBase`1.TrackLatency[TResult](Enum latencyMetadata  Func`1 method)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewSyncCommand`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<SyncCalendar>b__1()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceHelper.HandleResponseCode(ResponseCodeType responseCodeType  Action delegateAction  Action`1 handlerAction)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewSyncCommand`1.SyncCalendar(IExchangeService exchangeService  PagingTokenFlags flags  String& skipToken  String& deltaToken)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.CalendarViewTrackChangesCommand.InternalExecute(IExchangeService exchangeService)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ExchangeServiceCommand`2.InternalExecute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.<Execute>b__9_0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.RequestDetailsLoggerBase`1.TrackLatency[TResult](Enum latencyMetadata  Func`1 method)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.EntityContainersCommand`2.Execute()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Diagnostics.ServicesPerformanceTracker.RunOperationWithTrackingADAndRpcPerformance(Action method  Enum adCount  Enum adLatency  Enum rpcCount  Enum rpcLatency)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.Execute(ODataRequest request)
bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.RequestBroker.Dispatch(HttpContextBase httpContext  AsyncCallback asyncCallback  CheckpointTracker checkpointTracker  ServiceModel serviceModel  IComponentConfiguration`1 configuration);
```

How can I get rid of this error 500?